# Where to find - DataSet VC++ 2010 Ultimate..? Templates missing only in Visual C++..?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

I have Visual Studio 2010 ultimate...When I try to create a DataSet, it has missing from the templates...for Visual C++ only...But all others like C#, VB everywhere I have...Really Its giving headache...Only in Visual C++ its missing...I want to create a dataset & dataTable to send the data to Reports...But I can't found it..

And therefore I googled and found a advise to do the below

```
1.) I cleared ProjectTemplatesCache & ItemTemplates Cache..

2.) devenv.exe / installvstemplates
```

But No use....there I cant found the DataSet...Templates again.. So any advise for me?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature never existed in Visual Studio for C++ native projects, only for C++/CLI, and even for those, [it was disabled since Visual Studio 2008](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/292118/cannot-add-data-source-in-c-cli-winforms-project), a reply from a Microsoft representative at that page says:

> Visual Studio 2008 does not support adding new data sources (database
>   or webservice) to Visual C++ projects anymore.

As a workaround for C++/CLI, you could create an empty C# project, add your dataset there, and add a reference to it from your main project.

Comment: Hi, yms I found a sloution from Schemas to create DataSet via Codings... Thanks for the helps...

Comment: Also sorry for the delayed reply...because my system get formatted... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code is XML Schemas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
//DataSet Name - EmpDataSet
<xs:schema id="EmpDataSet" xmlns="urn:Emp" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" targetNamespace="urn:Emp" attributeFormDefault="qualified "
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name ="EmpDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice maxOccurs ="unbounded">
        <xs:element name ="EmpTable">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

              // Below Code is Column Fields

              <xs:element name ="sl_no" type ="xs:int" minOccurs ="0" />
              <xs:element name ="emp_no" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" />
              <xs:element name ="emp_detail" type ="xs:string" minOccurs ="0" />

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your comment. Usually typed datasets are created to reflect a database structure, so I thought you found a way to create the dataset programmatically from a database, sorry for the misunderstanding.